# Repopulate Dynamic Dropdown with "set_select" after Form Validation fails in Codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, html-select

I was wondering if it is possible to repopulate a dynamic `dropdown`(specifically the `option` of a `select`) after form validation fails which is generated by another `dropdown` at `on change event`.

My jQuery is working good on populating dynamic `option` of a `select` as well as at `server-side` when fetching the data, my only problem is when the form is submitted and validation fails, so basically the dynamic `select` `option/s` will reset.

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: where is your controller, view + jquery ajax code?

Comment: my controller, view as well as my jQuery has no problem, it's just I don't know if is possible to repopulate it again after populating dynamically when form validation fails. @M.Hemant

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here:

1) You manually set the 2x select fields with CI and repopulate/set them. You would construct these based on the `POST` values that were incorrect.

Assuming that list A populates list B which populates list C you may not want to do that. In which case you could define some hidden variables such as this:

```
var field1 = '<?php $_POST['field1']; ?>';
var field2 = '<?php $_POST['field2']; ?>';
var field3 = '<?php $_POST['field3']; ?>';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#field1').val(field1).trigger('change'); // or whatever on() query event you use
    $('#field2').val(field1).trigger('change'); // or whatever on() query event you use
    $('#field3').val(field1).trigger('change'); // or whatever on() query event you use
})
```

Might help? You would do the trigger to then load whichever lists/ajax calls populate each select box.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I just had an idea about your response, but the problem now is `trigger` doesn't fire, technically in my case. @Antony

Comment: How do you handle the select box changes? When a user changes a select box can you show us the code you use to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible,
this example works with Codeigniter 4 but I'm quite sure it works also with Codeigniter 3. Here I wanted to do a multiple dropdown field with Select2

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Categories</label>
    <?php
        $parameters = array('class' => 'form-control select2_cat', "multiple" => "multiple");
        $options = array();
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            $options[$cat['name']] = $cat['name'];
        }
        echo form_dropdown(
            'categories[]',
            $options,
            set_value('categories[]') != "" ? set_value('categories[]') : 0,
            $parameters
        ); 
    ?>
</div>
```

You see from the code, I'm using set_value() . I'm checking also if set_value is empty string.

You could find more info here: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/37330